# I've got 400 error, when send ajax request django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Want to make ajax-based authorization. 
Listing:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#activeform').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var _self = $(this);
        var token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: _self.attr('method'),
            url: _self.attr('action'),
            data: JSON.stringify({
                 "username": $('#id_username').val(),
                 "password1": $('#id_password1').val(),
                 "password2":  $('#id_password2').val(),
                 "csrfmiddlewaretoken": token}), 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
                    alert("Success")},
            error: function( xhr, textStatus ) {
                alert( [ xhr.status, textStatus ] )},
            complete: function() {
                    alert("Msg sended")},
            crossDomain: false
            });
});  </script>
```

Got 403 error, and success msg. How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's csrf protection expects the post data to be form encoded. You are submitting the data as JSON.

You can fix the problem by changing your javascript to submit form encoded data.

If you must submit JSON, then you'll need to use the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-protection) decorator to deactivate Django's CSRF checks. I wouldn't recommend doing this as it leaves your views vulnerable to CSRF attacks.